# Howto print from dumb terminals with local print server and remote hosted RDP

Tags: rdp, printing

We have essentially a remote office with about 5 dumb terminals.
The terminals are connecting to our office directly over a wireless link.

What I want to do is connect all their printers onto a print server.
But since the remote office is not actually allowed to see our LAN (since they are actually another company) we don't want a full on open VPN tunnel set up.  Naturally the RDP traffic passes through a firewall.

Is there an easy way to set up the RDP server so that it can see a print server on a remote LAN?

Comment: You may wish to clarify your network layout - I'm assuming you have site A and site B, with the RDP server in site A and the dumb terminals in site B. You want the RDP server to be able to print to a print server in site B.

How are the dumb terminals in site B communicating with the RDP server in site A if the RDP server can't see the print server in site B? Unless I have the wrong idea altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can set up a port forward on their firewall to pass lpd traffic to their print server.  Since they have a static ip that should work right?  I can ensure their firewall only allows LPD traffic from our external interface.